# Overriding inherited Datacontext

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, data-binding, windows-phone-8.1

I am having problem overriding the datacontext inherited from a parent. I have on global DataContext set, after that the Hub section Binds to an list in that model, which then propagates to the Listivew. Now each listview item is bound to an object, that also being the DataContext of the item. But each listview item has flyout. Now the flyout inherits the item DataContext and that is fine, but  one element in the Flyout has to be bound to a element of the initial global model.

So I currently have the following Page

```
<Page
x:Class="LocationSave.HubPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:LocationSave"
Name="root"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:i="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity"
xmlns:core="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core"
DataContext="{Binding DefaultViewModel, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
xmlns:data="using:LocationSave.Data"
mc:Ignorable="d" FontFamily="Global User Interface">

<Page.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Flyout  x:Name="Edit_Flyout">
            <Border  DataContext="{Binding}" >
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" > 
                    <ListView
                             DataContext= "{Binding The Problem is here}"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>

                    </ListView>
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
        </Flyout>

    </ResourceDictionary>
</Page.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Hub x:Name="Hub" x:Uid="Hub" >

        <HubSection x:Uid="Location_View" Header="Locations"
                    DataContext="{Binding Locations}" HeaderTemplate="{ThemeResource HubSectionHeaderTemplate}">
            <HubSection.Resources>


                <DataTemplate x:Key="Location_Item_Template">

                    <ListView 
                        AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ItemListViewSection5"
                        AutomationProperties.Name="Items In Group"
                        SelectionMode="None"
                        IsItemClickEnabled="True"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource LocationItem_Template}"
                        ItemClick="ItemView_ItemClick"
                        ContinuumNavigationTransitionInfo.ExitElementContainer="True"/>


                </DataTemplate>
            </HubSection.Resources>

            <StaticResource ResourceKey="Location_Item_Template"/>

        </HubSection>

    </Hub>
</Grid>
```

I tried setting the datacontext using paths etc, nothing seems to work and the inheritance not being overwritten correctly and DataContext is always null.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What exactly is the problem you are having? What have your tried? Have you tried to set the data context on the code behind?

Comment: It works if I set it in the Background, but that was not what I was looking for. I solved by adding a mapping to the source in the Static Resources. Will post it in a bit.

Comment: What binding expressions have you tried and what is the shape of your view model?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem where I wanted to override the inherited DataContext and use the default DataContext that I set for the entire page. I solved it by setting x:Name property on the Page element `<Page ... x:Name="MyPage">` and then bound to its data context using element name property of the Binding object like this: `Source="{Binding ElementName=MyPage, Path=DataContext.DesiredProperty}"`. Hope this helps somebody.

Answer (score 1):

So, I solved it by adding a CollectionViewSource  in the Page.Resources which pointed to the correct Property of the root ViewModel and with the correct DataContext.

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="SuggestionsModel" Source="{Binding Suggestions}"></CollectionViewSource>
```